# TypeScriptで既存の型を拡張する場合にthisの型を考慮したい

Tags: typescript

typescriptで既存の型を拡張する場合 interfaceを使って例えばsum関数であれば

```
interface Array<T>{
   sum():number;
}

Array.prototype.sum = function(){
   return this.reduce((i,j)=>i+j)
};
```

このように書けますが、上記の場合 number|stringの配列

```
[1,2,3,"4"].sum() //64
```

と書いてもコンパイルエラーになりません（当たり前ですが）
Array< number >にのみsumを追加させ
他の型ではコンパイルエラーにさせたいのですが可能でしょうか。

後

```
var a = [1,2,3,"4"].sum()
```

で a が コンパイル前はnumber型ですが実行時の型がstringと
間違った型になってしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず思いついた方法としては、下記の様な記述です。

`var a =`と書くと型推論によって`a`の型が決定されますので、型を明示する場合は`var a: number =`と書きます。

```
interface Array<T> {
    sum(): T;
}

Array.prototype.sum = function () {
    return this.reduce((i: any, j: any) => i + j);
};

// エラー: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
var a: number = [1, 2, 3, "4"].sum();

// OK
var num: number = [1, 2, 3, 4].sum(); // num === 10
var str: string = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].sum(); // str === "1234"

var numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var sum = numbers.sum();
```

Comment: これだと　型安全ですね！　ありがとうございます。

Array< number > だけにメソッドを生やすというのは無理なようですね。
しかし
`interface Array<T> {
    sum(): number;
}
var a:number = [1, 2, 3, "4"].sum();`

がコンパイルが通るのが納得いかない。。。

Comment: [1, 2, 3, "4"]の型はArray<string | number>で、sumはTに依らずnumberを返すので、コンパイルが通ってしまうのは仕方がないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: `this.reduce((i:number,j:number)=>i+j)`
とやってもコンパイルが通ってしまうので。。

Answer (score 1):

現在は [`this` の型を宣言](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function)できます。[2.0 から](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions)のようです。
よって、次のように書けます。

```js
interface Array<T> {
    sum(this: number[]): number
}

Array.prototype.sum = function sum(this: number[]): number {
    return this.reduce((i, j) => i + j)
}

let t = [1, 2, 3].sum()  // OK
```

これで、数値の配列以外に対し呼び出すとコンパイルエラーになります。

```js
let t2 = [1, 2, 3, "4"].sum()  // コンパイル時エラー
```